# Calculating Throughput... Please help!

Tags: firewall, switching

I have a Catalyst 3750 series switch-stack with 3 switches in the stack. All of my clients are connected to the 10/100 ports of the switch-stack.

I have 10 servers connected to 10/100/1000 SFP plugs (4 in each switch)

Our gateway (firewall) for all the clients and servers is plugged into one of the SFP 10/100/1000 ports of the switch-stack, and the firewall itself is a 10/100/1000 port...

Does all the traffic have to flow through the gateway (firewall), limiting throughput to the firewall's 10/100/1000 port?

I apologize if this is a silly question, but I really need help...

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Only traffic destined for a VLAN (subnet) which is different from the one on which it originated needs to travel through the router. Intra-VLAN traffic will not use a router, but inter-VLAN traffic will.